# exraer de un array los numeros mas grandes y mas pequeños que el que busca el usuario

Tags: java

mi programa consiste en los siguiente:
crea un `array` con una dimensión que se le pide al usuario (hecho)
rellenarlo con valores `double random` (hecho)
pedirle un valor al usuario y sacar de ese mismo `array` los que sean mas grandes ,y guardarlos en un `array`, y hacer lo mismo con el segundo.

Os adjunto el código:

```
public class otraspruevasarrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rant=new Random();
        double[] array=null;
        System.out.println("introdueix dimension arrays");
        int dimension=in.nextInt();

        array=new double[dimension];

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i]=rant.nextDouble()*100-0-0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %.2f",array[i]);
        }

        /*pedir un numero al usuario y guardar los numeros mas grandes que ese numero(de el array) e un array y los mas pequeños en otro*/

        System.out.println("itnroduce numero para buscar");
        double buscar=in.nextDouble();
        int tamanogrande=0;
        int tamanopequeno=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i]>buscar){
                tamanogrande++;
            }else if(array[i]<buscar){
                tamanopequeno++;
            }


        }

        double[]grandes=new double[tamanogrande];
        double[]pequenos=new double[tamanopequeno];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pequenos.length; j++) {
                for (int j2 = 0; j2 < grandes.length; j2++) {
                    if(array[i]>buscar){
                        tamanogrande++;
                grandes[j2]=array[i];
            }else if(array[i]<buscar){
                tamanopequeno++;
                pequenos[j]=array[i];
            }

                }
            }


        }
        System.out.println("lso mas grandes");
        for (int i = 0; i < grandes.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %.2f",grandes[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("lso mas peques");
        for (int i = 0; i < pequenos.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %.2f",pequenos[i]);
        }

     }

}
```

Y el output es el siguiente:

```
introdueix dimension arrays
3
 97,97 63,11 94,88itnroduce numero para buscar
90,23
lso mas grandes
 94,88 94,88lso mas peques
 63,11
```

Como podéis ver de los mas grandes solo me saca uno y me lo repite.

¿Cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio tienes un lió con los for, ya que no hace falta 3 for para lo que quieres y claro el primer for esta bien porque con este recorres los números del array, pero los dos siguientes for no tienen sentido y es el que te duplica en el caso de ser números grandes.

Adjunto modificación con un resultado correcto:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rant=new Random();
        double[] array=null;
        System.out.println("introduce dimension arrays: ");
        int dimension=in.nextInt();

        array=new double[dimension];

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i]=rant.nextDouble()*100-0-0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %.2f",array[i]);
        }

        /*pedir un numero al usuario y guardar los numeros mas grandes que ese numero(de el array) e un array y los mas pequeños en otro*/

        System.out.println("\nintroduce numero para buscar: ");
        double buscar=in.nextDouble();
        int tamanogrande=0;
        int tamanopequeno=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i]>buscar){
                tamanogrande++;
            }else if(array[i]<buscar){
                tamanopequeno++;
            }    
        }

        double[]grandes=new double[tamanogrande];
        double[]pequenos=new double[tamanopequeno];

        int contadorGrandes = 0;
        int contadorPequeno = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if ( array[i] > buscar){
                grandes[contadorGrandes] = array[i];
                contadorGrandes++;
            }
            else{
                pequenos[contadorPequeno] = array[i];
                contadorPequeno++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("los más grandes");
        for (int i = 0; i < grandes.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %.2f",grandes[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\nlos más peques");
        for (int i = 0; i < pequenos.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(" %.2f",pequenos[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la parte que he modificado

```
    int contadorGrandes = 0;
    int contadorPequeno = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ( array[i] > buscar){
            grandes[contadorGrandes] = array[i];
            contadorGrandes++;
        }
        else{
            pequenos[contadorPequeno] = array[i];
            contadorPequeno++;
        }
    }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad,yo pensaba que era necesario un triple for para poder recorrer las otras 2 arrays ya que tienen dimensiones distintas al original

Comment: De nada. No se si esto es para clase y solo tienes que usar arrays, pero para evitar los indices y calculo de tamaños de los arrays grande y pequeño lo suyo sería usar ArrayList, ya que usando esto no hace falta definir un tamaño. Saludos.

Comment: Solo un pequeño detalle. En el else que haces para inserta los menores, debería ser un else if(array[i]<buscar) porque si es igual también lo metes y no deberías.

Answer (score 0):

Haces una cosa muy rara para ver qué números metes al array de grandes y cuál al de pequeños. Puedes hacerlo de la misma manera que haces para calcular sus tamaños.

```
public class otraspruevasarrays {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rant=new Random();
    double[] array=null;
    System.out.println("introdueix dimension arrays");
    int dimension=in.nextInt();

    array=new double[dimension];

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i]=rant.nextDouble()*100-0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf(" %.2f \n",array[i]);
    }

    /*pedir un numero al usuario y guardar los numeros mas grandes que ese numero(de el array) e un array y los mas pequeños en otro*/

    System.out.println("itnroduce numero para buscar");
    double buscar=in.nextDouble();
    int tamanogrande=0;
    int tamanopequeno=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i]>buscar){
            tamanogrande++;
        }else if(array[i]<buscar){
            tamanopequeno++;
        }
    }

    double[]grandes=new double[tamanogrande];
    double[]pequenos=new double[tamanopequeno];
    int posGran = 0;  //Indice para ir metiendo los mayores al array
    int posPeq = 0;  //Indice para ir metiendo los menores al array


    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  //Recorremos el array para comprobar los números
        if(array[i]<buscar){
            pequenos[posPeq] = array[i];  //Si es menor lo metemos en su array e incrementamos el índice
            posPeq++;
        }else if(array[i]>buscar){
            grandes[posGran] = array[i];   //Si es mayor lo metemos en su array e incrementamos el índice
            posGran++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("los mas grandes");
    for (int i = 0; i < grandes.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf(" %.2f",grandes[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("\nlos mas peques");
    for (int i = 0; i < pequenos.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf(" %.2f",pequenos[i]);
    }
  }
}
```